# youtube HD embed + full screen enabled not working

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

Thanks to another answer I managed to "force" the HD embed as default in a youtube video. Unfortunately it seems that this doesn't co-exist well with the full screen enabled

both

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W33zQcIoxhQ?vq=hd720"
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">  </iframe> or just with <iframe width="640"   
height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/083l_FSheWE?vq=hd1080" frameborder="0"
 allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

are working in terms of showing an HD default but do not allow the full screen mode (there is no icon in the youtube player). Thanks in advance for your help!